# Change Resolution of iOS System Button

Tags: ios, swift

My app adds buttons (as sub views) to a very large image which is itself inside of a scroll view.  Everything works as intended (the user can zoom around and click the buttons), but the problem is that iOS system buttons seem to default to a very low resolution, and consequently look very bad when my large image is zoomed (see below).

Is there an easy way to change that resolution, or am I stuck supplying a high resolution image myself?  If I'm stuck with the latter solution, then what am I to do if the button needs to contain dynamic elements which can't be supplied by me such as text?

I'm guessing that the solution is to add the button somewhere other than its current position in the view hierarchy (scroll view -> image view -> sub view), but I'm unsure where that would be.

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: You need to supply proper resolution image to button. Have a look on this - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I can see how you could do that for a single image, but what about something more dynamic like text?